# How to reuse an array in a schema?

Tags: yaml, jsonschema

The following schema doesn't pass the validation with [jsonschema](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

```
$defs:
    names:
    - n1
    - n2
    - n3
properties:
    name:
        enum:
            $ref: "#/$defs/names"
```

With a minimal fragment such as `name: "n1"`, jsonschema will complain `jsonschema.exceptions.SchemaError: ['n1', 'n2', 'n3'] is not of type 'object', 'boolean'`.

So can I put an array in a schema's `$defs`? I don't see this limitation in [the tutorial on json-schema.org](http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#defs). If not, how can I reuse an array in a schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `enum` property expects a a list of values not a schema (via the `$ref` keyword). Second, the schemas in `$defs` (in your example `names`) have to be a schema - directly setting a list indeed doesn't work.

To make your example work, you have to use the `enum` keyword as part of the `$defs` schema like this:

```yaml
"$defs":
  names:
    enum:
    - n1
    - n2
    - n2
properties:
  name:
    "$ref": "#/$defs/names"
```

This allows you to validate as expected: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/RGx6COQf

Comment: So is there a way to reuse an array, say, if I want to use the array both in `enum` and `allOf`?

Comment: You can use the array in the `enum` / `$defs` to define a sub-schema (as done above) and then refer the sub-schema in the `allOf`:`allOf: [{"$ref": "#/$defs/names"}, {<other sub-schema>}]`. You always have to think in "(sub-)schemas" as defined by JsonSchema instead of values like like array as the building blocks for advanced JsonSchemas.